# Detailed log of executing java ee application in production

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jvm

I want to know if it is possible to log the execution of all the instructions in a method of a java ee application in production. This should provide the values of the attributes and whether the instruction has been correctly executed.

I know about the basic log provided by application servers like glassfish but I want to have the history of a detailed execution with the values of the variables at any previous time.

Best regards

Comment: This cries for [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/)...

Comment: 1. `This should provide the values of the attributes and whether the instruction has been correctly executed.`: do you mean method params or `attributes`? 2. What JavaEE components are you trying to log?

Comment: I think the question is clear I want to track the attribute values and the methods called at any previous time.

Comment: Are you looking for a code-based or config-based solution?

Comment: @kolossus I am looking for both of them. But the code -based solution interest me the most.

Comment: There is a partial solution in JavaEE for your requirement. But the solution will not be able to tell you which instructions are executed (at least not known to me). It can tell you which class, which method and what method params are passed in. The question is if that is enough for you.

Comment: @belkebir you can use this library http://aspect4log.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 7):

What you describe is handily covered by the [`@AroundInvoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/AroundInvoke.html) interceptor, one of a handful of interceptors supported by CDI. It's still based on the AOP approach and is analogous to what the other answer has from AspectJ. Logging is the go-to example for illustrating this kind of interceptor, so let's consider the following `MethodLogger`.

1. Define a class `MethodLogger`. This is the class to which you'll delegate the actual logging. It's also in this class that you'll have access to the information you're looking for (method name, completion of execution, parameters e.t.c.)

   ```
   public class MethodLogger{
      private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.you.MethodLogger");  

      @AroundInvoke
      public Object logIt(InvocationContext iCtxt) throws Exception{
          logger.entering(iCtxt.getTarget().toString(),iCtxt.getMethod().getName(),iCtxt.getParameters());

          try{
              return iCtxt.proceed(); //important! otherwise, method invocation doesn't continue
           }
           catch(Exception ex){
               //do whatever you want whenever an exception occurs during this process
           }
           finally{
              logger.exiting(iCtxt.getTarget().toString(),iCtxt.getMethod().getName());
           }  

      }

   }
   ```
2. Apply your interceptor to your EJB

   ```
   @Stateless
   @Interceptors(MethodLogger.class) //apply this annotation to intercept every method call on this EJB
   public class YourEJB{
       @Interceptors(MethodLogger.class) // apply here if you want only a specific method to be tracked
       public void doSomething();

       @ExcludeClassInterceptors //apply this to stop the interceptor from affecting this method
       public void doSomethingElse();


   }
   ```

From EJB 3.1, you also have the option to specify global interceptors. Interceptors so-defined will apply to all EJBs in an application, regardless of annotation use. So in *ejb-jar.xml*:

```
<assembly-descriptor>
  <interceptor-binding>
     <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
     <interceptor-class>com.you.MethodLogger</interceptor-class>
  </interceptor-binding>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

**Further Reading**

- [Oracle's EJB Interceptor Tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think Aspect Oriented Programming(AOP) is what you should try out. If you are familiar with the Spring framework, it has a pretty extensive set of AOP features.

A sample that I created when I wanted to see the parameters being passed in (Just to avoid the pain of debugging in Eclipse)

```
    @Around("execution(public void getPersonCount())")
    public void thirdAdvice(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        final int numberOfArguments = joinPoint.getArgs().length;
        final String functionName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        System.out.println("Number of arguments = " + numberOfArguments);
        System.out.println("Function name = " + functionName);
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }
```

You can read more about AOP [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Also, in my example, I have output the value to the standard output. You can probably output it to a file on the disk along with the time.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to this in J2EE?

Comment: I have another question regarding this solution? Is it possible to see the instructions that have been executed? let say we have an if-else and I want to see if the if has been executed or the else statement. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Well i haven't worked much on J2EE, so I cannot tell you about alternatives for this in J2EE. As for the if-else part, I don't think we can do that in AOP as well.

Comment: The AOP wraps the method calls, so it can tell if the method has been invoked but it can't tell what happens inside the method. You might be able to infer the if/else blocks if they call other methods but that won't really help you in this case.